# L'hopital rule - Is it okay if I have $\frac {0-0} 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know how to use L'hopital rule. but there is something I would like to know, since i saw some stuff like that, but I managed to get rid of it somehow, now I could not.
if I have: $\frac {0-0} 0$, is it allowed to use L'hopital or only $\frac {0} 0$ and infinity of course, but I mean with the subtraction, is it allowed?

Edit: believe me, I searched it online, could not find anything.. maybe I didn't know what to write, but if you write: L'hopital rule if I have (0-0/0), you wont find anything for it...  )

Edit: didnt explain myself good, here is the limit:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2-\sin^2\left(x\right)}{\:x^2\sin^2\left(x\right)}\right)$$
I have $\frac {0-0} 0$

Comment: $0-0=0$ why not?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example that shows it is not the same as a $0/0$ case?

Comment: Oh I probably didnt explain myself, I will edit. I mean, lets say I have limit $$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2-sin^2\left(x\right)}{\:x^2sin^2\left(x\right)}\right)$$, I have here the $\frac {0-0} 0$ I will edit.

Comment: Is it okay to use lhopital here? since I do have 0 to 0, but the problem is 0-0 to 0

Comment: 0 - 0 = 0, I don't see the problem here.

Comment: The limit I just uploaded, its allowed to do Lhopital? since its not exactly 0 to 0, its (0-0 to  0), that is my problem to understand @FatsoBoo

Comment: $0-0 = 0$ is not an indeterminate form, it's just 0, so yes this is fine.

Comment: Thanks :) its weird I didn't know it before, used Lhopital alot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use the L' Hopital rule. This is because it doesn't matter if there is a 0 - 0 in the numerator. All that matters is that the numerator is ultimately equal to 0.

Comment: Oh very good!! thanks!! it helps me alot!!

Comment: in a few minutes I will be able to upload and make the answer V, if anybody sees, I am all good now :) Thanks all.